# How to allow form to be submitted once required fields are completed?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, onsubmit

I have completed code with immediate field validation, but also want to prevent the form from being submitted if the fields do not have a value. I've managed to prevent the form from being submitted, but when I go back and provide a value, it still won't allow it to submit. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="contactForm" action="https://formspree.io/xrggbejj" method="POST" onsubmit="return formValidation(contactForm);">

  <div class="row">

  <div class="col">
    <label for="fName">First Name</label>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" id="fName" name="firstname" onblur="checkFirstName(firstName)" autofocus/>
    <img src="../images/alert-icon.png" class="alert" id="firstNameMsg" alt="alert icon" width="40" height="35"/>
  </div>
  </div> <!-- End of row -->

  <div class="row">

  <div class="col">
    <label for="lName">Last Name</label>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" id="lName" name="lastname" onblur="checkLastName(lastName)"/>
    <img src="../images/alert-icon.png" class="alert" id="lastNameMsg" alt="alert icon" width="40" height="35"/>
  </div>
  </div> <!-- End of row -->

  <div class="row">

  <div class="col">
    <label for="subject">Questions and/or Comments</label>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" onblur="checkSubject(subject)" style="height:200px"></textarea>
    <img src="../images/alert-icon.png" class="alert" id="subjectMsg" alt="alert icon" width="40" height="35"/>
  </div>
  </div> <!-- End of row -->

  <div class="row">
    <input type="submit" value="SEND" />
  </div> <!-- End of row -->
</form>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

Contact form field validation

```
var alertStyle;
var alertImg;
const firstName = document.forms['contactForm']['fName'];
const lastName = document.forms['contactForm']['lName'];
const subject = document.forms['contactForm']['subject'];

function checkFirstName(firstName) {

  if (firstName.value === '') {
    alertStyle = document.getElementById('fName').style.border = '2px solid rgba(255, 6, 0)';
    alertImg = document.getElementById('firstNameMsg').style.display = 'inline-block';
    return false;
  } else if (firstName.value !== '') {
    alertStyle = document.getElementById('fName').style.border = '1px solid #ccc';
   alertImg = document.getElementById('firstNameMsg').style.display = 'none';
   return true;
 }
}

function checkLastName(lastName) {

  if (lastName.value === '') {
    alertStyle = document.getElementById('lName').style.border = '2px solid rgba(255, 6, 0)';
    alertImg = document.getElementById('lastNameMsg').style.display = 'inline-block';
    return false;
  } else if (lastName.value !== '') {
    alertStyle = document.getElementById('lName').style.border = '1px solid #ccc';
    alertImg = document.getElementById('lastNameMsg').style.display = 'none';
    return true;
 }
}

function checkSubject(subject) {

  if (subject.value === '') {
    alertStyle = document.getElementById('subject').style.border = '2px solid rgba(255, 6, 0)';
    alertImg = document.getElementById('subjectMsg').style.display = 'inline-block';
    return false;
  } else if (firstName.value !== '') {
    alertStyle = document.getElementById('subject').style.border = '1px solid #ccc';
    alertImg = document.getElementById('subjectMsg').style.display = 'none';
    return true;
}}
```

Contact form validation on submit

```
function formValidation(contactForm) {

  if (firstName && lastName && subject !== true) {
    alert('Please fill out required fields.')
    event.preventDefault()
    return false;
  } else if (firstName && lastName && subject === true) {
    return true;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `firstName`, `lastName`, and `subject` variable are pointing to the input not the actual value inside of them. You can modify your function to

```
    function formValidation(contactForm) {

      if (!firstName.value || !lastName.value || !subject.value) {
        alert('Please fill out required fields.')
        event.preventDefault()
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
```

Here I used the `!` operator to convert the inputs to `True` when they are empty and if any of the inputs are empty the first case will evaluate, else your function will return true.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing this

```
if (firstName && lastName && subject !== true) {
  ...
}
```

I assume you expect doing this

```
 if (firstName.value === '') {
    alertStyle = document.getElementById('fName').style.border = '2px solid rgba(255, 6, 0)';
    alertImg = document.getElementById('firstNameMsg').style.display = 'inline-block';
    return false;
```

Would do something like this

```
firstName = true
```

But it doesn't actually assign anything to `firstName`. It just returns true.

You could have a variable like `isValid` and do `isValid = true` instead of returning true in your `checkLastName() etc..`

However, since you are doing this

```
document.getElementById('lastNameMsg').style.display = 'none'
```

You could do

```
function formValidation(contactForm) {

  if (document.getElementById('lastNameMsg').style.display !== 'none') {
    alert('Please fill out required fields.')
    event.preventDefault()
    return false;
  } else if (document.getElementById('lastNameMsg').style.display === 'none') {
    return true;
 }
}
```

Anyways, there are multiple ways this could be simplified but hopefully this gets you going :)

Cheers.